# Creating Encrypted Zip in Codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, zip, system

In my Codeigniter Controller I have the following code that zip the backup file from database. The problem is that when I extract the zip file, instead of single file inside, there are other folder from the path inside of it.

```
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $this->load->helper('date');
    $this->load->helper('file');

    set_time_limit(0);

    $prefs = array(
    'format'        => 'txt',                       // gzip, zip, txt
    'filename'      => 'backup.sql',              // File name - NEEDED ONLY WITH ZIP FILES
    'add_drop'      => TRUE,                        // Whether to add DROP TABLE statements to backup file
    'add_insert'    => TRUE,                        // Whether to add INSERT data to backup file
    'newline'       => "\n"                         // Newline character used in backup file
    );


    $backup = $this->dbutil->backup($prefs);


    $file = FCPATH.'GB_dump_backup/backup.txt';
    $zip = FCPATH.'GB_dump_backup/'.now().'backup';

    write_file($file, $backup);

    system('zip -P pass '.$zip.' '.$file .' ');
```

I'm not sure why the zip creates path folder inside the zip too. I mean instead of just archiving the backup.txt , it backup from the Application folder till to backup.txt file. After extracting the zip file I get below picture :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` includes the paths to the files in the zip folder it creates by default. Add the `-j` flag to `j`unk the paths and only include the file.

```
system('zip -j -P pass '.$zip.' '.$file .' ');
```

Check out the man page for `zip` for more info.

```
$man zip
...
   -p
   --paths
          Include relative file paths as part of the names of files stored in the ar-
          chive.  This is the default.  The -j option junks the paths and just stores
          the names of the files.
```